# GAE datastore - How to deal with multiple namespace at same time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I design hierarchical entity with namespace, and use it with default namespace in single request?

Default namespace is used for administrative purpose, like holding informations about admin of each namespace.

#### Hierarchy

```
User (Namespace: default)
  - Organization (Namespace: default)
    - User (Namespace: name of organization)
```

#### Summary:

1.
How can I use multiple namespace in single request?
 - Available

2.
Is `NamespaceManager.set()` should be called before `Key.create`, or before datastore operation?

----- Update -----

    `Key key = KeyFactory.createKey('Test', 100)
    NamespaceManager.set('NS_NEW')
    Key nsKey = KeyFactory.createKey('Test', 100)
    NamespaceManager.set(null)
    [key: key, nsKey: nsKey];`

Result :

```
{"key": {"kind":"Test","appId":"gaetest","id":100,"name":null,"parent":null,"namespace":"","complete":true},"nsKey":{"kind":"Test","appId":"gaetest","id":100,"name":null,"parent":null,"namespace":"NS_NEW","complete":true}}
```

According to result, Key holds namespace. 
(And objectify becomes problem..)

3.
If I need to do this with entity group (parent key), how can I bypass concurrent query limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether the the app engine datastore supports cross-namespace entities, the answer is no. Entities live within a single namespace (the namespace embedded in the Entity key). It's possible to store, as an Entity property value, a key to an Entity in a different namespace, but I don't know enough about Objectify to say whether Objectify supports that, or whether you'd need to bypass Objectify to use a lower-level API.

If you're asking whether you can use multiple namespaces with a HTTP request, the answer is clearly yes, since the handler starts in the default namespace until the namespace is changed by code within the handler. If you're asking whether you can use multiple namespaces within a datastore query (say, to join data from different namespaces), the answer (as I understand it) is no.

Comment: Objectify does not support this.. And I'm working on custom mapper.

Comment: I seem to be able to store entities with Refs to entities in other namespaces just fine using objectify with one exception:  You can't have a parent in another namespace... the namespace is prefixed onto the key and the parent key is part of your key, so the child will always follow the parent (which is probably to be expected).